# Declare static variable contains the address to another static variable

Tags: c, rust, embedded

I am trying to translate some old embedded C codes to Rust, but I meet with some problems.

When I was using C, I can use the reference (e.g. `arr`, when `arr` is an array) to another variable to initialize a global variable. For example:

```c
#define MASK 0xffff0000

int arr[128] = {0};
uint64_t arr_table[2] = {arr + MASK, 0};
```

I have to declare them at the compile time, so that they can be accessed from extern libraries (e.g. kernel assembly codes).

Is there any equivalent in Rust?

## What I have tried

```rust
pub static arr: [u32; 128] = [0; 128];
pub static arr_table: [u64; 2] = [&arr as *const [u32; 128] as u64 + MASK, 0];
```

The compiler told me:

```
error: pointers cannot be cast to integers during const eval

note: at compile-time, pointers do not have an integer value
note: avoiding this restriction via `transmute`, `union`, or raw pointers leads to compile-time undefined behavior
```

I have also tried `mem::transmute()` to do an unsafe conversion to `u64`, and the compiler complaint the same thing:

```
error[E0080]: could not evaluate static initializer

help: this code performed an operation that depends on the underlying bytes representing a pointer
help: the absolute address of a pointer is not known at compile-time, so such operations are not supported
```

## Question

I know it is impossible for the compiler to know the exact address of a static variable at the compile time.

I am not so familiar with the mechanism behind compilation, but I suppose that C has put off the work till link process and implied the linker to give the right values to `arr_table`. I wonder if it is possible to do the same thing in Rust? Thanks!

Comment: I read that Rust has ['memory safety'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust_(programming_language)#Memory_safety) so I don't expect this to be possible in any way. Adding a 'random' value to a pointer is allowed in C at compile time, but of course can lead to a run-time crash.

Comment: @meaning-matters "_Adding a 'random' value to a pointer is allowed in C_": does C pick a random value to initialize `arr_table` (which also goes into the final executable file) too? Then it is weird that the C program works fine and `arr_table[0]` does point to `arr + MASK`.

Comment: `arr_table[2]` is initialised with a pointer, so why is it `uint64_t`? The behaviour will be further undermined by `arr + MASK` being outside the address range of the object. It is the value of `MASK` which is effectively random. You should start from sensible, valid code. The `arr_table[0]` does *not* "point to `arr + MASK`": it isn't a pointer.

Comment: Apologies for being unclear.  I meant to generalise that adding any number to a pointer ...

Comment: @WeatherVane oh I forgot to clarify my intention: I am developing for a 64-bit ARM embedded platform, so the address of any object should be within 64-bit unsigned integer. The action, offsetting 
 a pointer by a `MASK`, is to convert a virtual address to a physical one, which is later passed to the kernel to access `arr`, so `arr + MASK` is sensible, at least for the kernel.

Comment: Why would you want to use Rust for low level stuff?  Does Rust allow calling a C library?

Comment: @meaning-matters Of course it [can](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/interoperability/c-with-rust.html). But it is off-topic.

Comment: @w568w Thanks for the link and this question.  I'm new to Rust.  Interesting language.

Comment: Is it important for you that the type of second variable is `[u64; 2]` ? Can you make it like `[*const T; 2]` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to build on stable, but there was a fair amount of compiler fight. The short version is that this happens because you're trying to write C-like code in rust that the borrow checker fundamentally can't check, so you are somewhat fighting the language by doing this. You will still be able to do it but the `unsafe` keyword will have to be used in declaring and in using variables like this.

I think it would be much better if you can just store normal rust references instead of pointers.

Nevertheless, this version which is closer to what you originally wrote will build:

```
const MASK: isize = 42;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct MyU32Ptr(*const u32);

unsafe impl Sync for MyU32Ptr {}

pub static ARR: [u32; 128] = [0; 128];
pub static ARR_TABLE: [MyU32Ptr; 2] = [MyU32Ptr(unsafe { (&ARR as *const u32).offset(MASK) }), MyU32Ptr(core::ptr::null())];
```

The main ideas here are:

1. `*const u32` does not implement `Sync`, it's not considered safe to share this value across threads. This is because while rust references have lifetimes and language rules prevent that a `&` and a `&mut` to the same variable can exist at the same time, pointers don't have any of that and represent an escape hatch away from those constraints. The consequence of that is that a lot of things you would want to do with pointers are unsafe. Passing a pointer from one thread to another, or creating a pointer that all threads can see, has to be unsafe, or else it would be impossible for any thread to create a `&mut` to do that data ever safely.

   To make this build anyways, what I did is implement a new-type wrapper around `*const u32` which I called `MyU32Ptr`, gave it `Repr(C)` so that it is guaranteed by the language to be the same ABI as a C pointer, and then I just declared that this type is `Sync`, using `unsafe impl Sync`. That is dirty, but in our case, we may feel okay doing this, knowing that `MyU32Ptr` won't be used to point to anything that is changing at runtime anyways.
2. I replaced your integers with `*const u32`, and your pointer arithmetic with a call to `.offset` which is in my understanding the more recommendable way to do this nowadays (see the ["strict provenance" tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/95228) if you are interested). Since this function is unsafe we have to add an unsafe block when we call it.

It seemed to me that logically you wanted these to be pointers to arrays and it wasn't important to make them integers. I think you can make the calling code convert them to integers if you actually need that for some reason.

---

I think the most idiomatic way to have tables of arrays like you are doing here right now is to use references and not pointers.

```
pub static ARR: [u32; 128] = [0; 128];
pub static ARR_TABLE: [&[u32]; 1] = [&ARR];
pub static ANOTHER_ARR_TABLE: [Option<&[u32]>; 2] = [Some(&ARR), None];
```

(Note that in rust, `Option<&T>` has the same in-memory representation as `* const T`, it's just that it's more idiomatic in rust than having "maybe null pointers", and it can be used and passed around threads by safe code, because it is an honest borrow-checked reference.)

However, I wasn't able to get the `+MASK` part to work, you get errors where the compiler complains that "slice" indexing is not a const function.

I think this is related to this rustlang issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/73083

You might be able to get away with like, references to u32s instead of slices, `[Option<&u32>; 2]` if that can meet your needs. I think you might also be able to use a stopgap crate like [`konst` crate](https://crates.io/crates/konst) to do work around this until they stabilize something around this.

HTH

Comment: Very useful and comprehensive, thanks a lot! After reading your answer and doing some research, I would like to suggest three possible improvements in the answer: 1. `.offset(1)` will increase the pointer address by the size of its point type (e.g. 4 Bytes for `*const u32`, 8 Bytes for `*const u64`), so it is better to use a one-byte type, such as `*const u8`; 2. `static mut` [works like a sugar](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-is-static-mut-bad/32888/2) for storing static but thread-unsafe variables, by wrapping the type with a `UnsafeCell<T>`, so you do not need to wrap it manually.

Comment: (continued) 3. when passing `offset()` a very large value (e.g. the actual mask value in my project, `0xffff000000000000`), it will doubt that the pointer will overflow or go over the data type's bound, and abort the compilation. In that case, `wrapping_offset()` works better because it puts off the requirements to runtime, according to the documentation.